# No se muestra JFrame creado

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy empezando a programar en Java y me he encontrado con este problema, estoy usando `Eclipse`, la cosa es que al momento de ejecutar el programa no se visualiza el `JFrame` contenedor de los demás `JPanel`, y no logro ver el error

```
 public class AddClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener
  {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        //ATTR'S
        private JFrame Frame;
        private JPanel RPanel, LPanel, UPanel, CPanel;
        private JButton LButton1, LButton2, LButton3;
        private JButton RButton1, RButton2, RButton3;
        private JButton UButton1, UButton2, UButton3;
        private JButton CButton1, CButton2, CButton3;
        private Container Cont;


    //Constructor 
    public AddClient()
    {
        this.CPanel = null;
        this.Frame = null;
        this.RPanel = null;
        this.LPanel = null;
        this.UPanel = null;
        this.CPanel = null;
        this.RButton1 = null;
        this.RButton2 = null;
        this.RButton3 = null;
        this.LButton1 = null;
        this.LButton2 = null;
        this.LButton3 = null;
        this.UButton1 = null;
        this.UButton2 = null;
        this.UButton3 = null;
        this.CButton1 = null;
        this.CButton2 = null;
        this.CButton3 = null;
        this.Cont = null;


         makeLPanel();
         makeRPanel();
         makeUPanel();
         makeCPanel();
         makeWindow();

    }

    // funcion para hacer el panes izquierdo
    public void makeLPanel()
    {
        this.LPanel = new JPanel();
        this.LButton1 = new JButton("LBoton1");
        this.LButton2 = new JButton("LBoton2");
        this.LButton3 = new JButton("LBoton3");
        this.LPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(LPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.LPanel.add(this.LButton1);
        this.LPanel.add(this.LButton2);
        this.LPanel.add(this.LButton3);

    }

    // funcion para hacer el panel Derecho
    public void makeRPanel()
    {
        this.RPanel = new JPanel();
        this.RButton1 = new JButton("RBoton1");
        this.RButton2 = new JButton("RBoton2");
        this.RButton3 = new JButton("RBoton3");
        this.RPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(RPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.RPanel.add(this.RButton1);
        this.RPanel.add(this.RButton2);
        this.RPanel.add(this.RButton3);
    }

    // FUNCION creacion de Panel Superior

    public void makeUPanel()
    {
        this.UPanel = new JPanel();
        this.UButton1 = new JButton("UBoton1");
        this.UButton2 = new JButton("UBoton2");
        this.UButton3 = new JButton("UBoton3");
        this.UPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.UPanel.add(this.UButton1);
        this.UPanel.add(this.UButton2);
        this.UPanel.add(this.UButton3);
    }

    //Panel Central
        public void makeCPanel()
        {
            this.CPanel = new JPanel();
            this.CButton1 = new JButton("LBoton1");
            this.CButton2 = new JButton("LBoton2");
            this.CButton3 = new JButton("LBoton3");
            this.CPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(CPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            this.CPanel.add(this.CButton1);
            this.CPanel.add(this.CButton2);
            this.CPanel.add(this.CButton3);
        }

    //Creamos Ventana principal

    public void makeWindow()
    {
        this.Frame = new JFrame();
        this.Frame.setTitle("Gestion de Bienes Raices");
        this.Frame.setSize(1000, 900);
        this.Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.Frame.setResizable(false);
        Cont = Frame.getContentPane();
        Cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Cont.add(this.UPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Cont.add(this.CPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Cont.add(this.RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        Cont.add(this.LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);


    }


    /* esto va en la clase main de nombre
      RealState y pretendo llamar la clase addClient 
       desde acá y cargar el JFrame. */

    public class RealState {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Inicializamos 
        AddClient pf = new AddClient();
        pf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No incluiste la declaración de clase de `AddClient`, pero supongo si te permite llamar `setVisible()` a la instancia que es un:

```
public class AddClient extends JFrame{
```

Si eso es el caso, es obvio porque no ves nada:

en `makeWindow()` instas un nuevo JFrame que nunca haces visible.

```
public void makeWindow()
{
    this.Frame = new JFrame();
    this.Frame.setTitle("Gestion de Bienes Raices");
    this.Frame.setSize(1000, 900);
    this.Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.Frame.setResizable(false);
    Cont = Frame.getContentPane();
    Cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Cont.add(this.UPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Cont.add(this.CPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Cont.add(this.RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    Cont.add(this.LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    // eso funciona:
    this.Frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

En todo caso te recomiendo refacturar tu código a una clase que extende `JFrame` y luego solamente construyes un contenedor de tu gusto y lo agregas como `contentPane`. en este caso tu código sería:

```
public void makeWindow()
{
    this.setTitle("Gestion de Bienes Raices");
    this.setSize(1000, 900);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    Cont = getContentPane();
    Cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Cont.add(this.UPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Cont.add(this.CPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Cont.add(this.RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    Cont.add(this.LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```

Eso funciona también con el código en tu `main`.

Finalmente dejame consejarte: si quieres hacer la vida de tus pares más facil en encontrar tus errores, considera seguir las practicas comúnes de formato de nombres de variables, clases y constantes:

- métodos minúsculas con camelCase, empezando con un verbo (eje `getContentPane()`)
- variables minusculas con camelCase: (eje `fichaTecnica`)
- clases empezando con mayúsculas, luego camelCase (eje `AddClient`)
- constantes mayusculas (eje `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`)

Comment: La clase que extiende de JFrame si esta creada, por error mio no la coloqué en el codigo, y como es eso de que en makeWindow() instancio un frame que nunca hago visible?, mi idea era hacer 4 funciones una para cada panel y un JFrame que contenga los 4 que ya cree.

Comment: Aquí esta tu tema: tu extendes JFrame (frame 1), además mantienes un campo JFrame Frame. En tu código armas este campo, pero al fin en main llamas al **otro** JFrame (el mismo que instaste con new AddClient) con setVisible. Mi respuesta tiene 2 soluciones, te recomiendo la segunda.

Comment: Me has ayudado muchisimo , no entendia el tema de al extender de JFrame ya estaba creando uno y para mi caso no habia necesidad de crear  otro ,me limité a eliminar el Segundo JFrame que creé y ya pude ver las demás cosas . muchas gracias también seguiré tu consejo para mejorar mis prácticas  como programador Feliz Noche para ti.

Comment: @AlvaroSantafe de nada, te recomiendo estudiar un poco sobre POO, herencia y estas conceptos en general, te va ayudar mucho de empezar por los básicos, el crecimiento se pone más rapido despues con un buen fundamento.

Comment: @AlvaroSantafe Otra mejora es no utilizar `extends JFrame implements ActionListener` uno intenta favorecer la composición en vez de utilizar herencia, y luego haciendolo ActionListener rompes el principio de responsabilidad simple

Answer (score 0):

Al Agregar los componentes a tu contenedor , lo añades a un variable de tipo `Container`  que contiene el `ContentPane` de tu JFrame creado en el método `makeWindow` , y en el método `main` creas e instancias tu clase `AddClient` que se comporta como un `JFrame` pero no contiene tus componentes. posible solución *(no la mejor)* es desde la clase `main` acceder a tu variable `Frame`

```
 public  static void main(String[] args) {
    AddClient pf = new AddClient();
    pf.Frame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Tener en cuenta que si la clase Extiende de `JFrame` No hace falta crear una nueva instancia de `JFrame` ya que la clase se comportará como un `JFrame` , además se puede agregar componentes sin llamar a `getContentPane` ,si no directamente con el método `add`

```
public void makeWindow()
{
    setTitle("Gestion de Bienes Raices");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(this.UPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(this.CPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(this.RPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(this.LPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```